# SKPayment / SKPaymentQueue: Cannot connect to iTunes Store

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, skpaymenttransaction

I am building an App with IAP (auto-renewal subscription). The workflow seems to work fine, IPA are created for sure (in iTunes connect), sandbox user also logged in. The IAP product ID is also correct but I get the error (from `SKPaymentTransaction`):

`Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"`

Before that error I get the purchase screens where the price, the duration of the subscription and the name of the subscription is displayed. So the connection and the product ID is correct.

I am logged in with sandbox user: The screens displays `[Environment: Sandbox]`.

I am using a real device (iPhone 7 and iPhone 5). The error occurs on both devices and on simulator (for sure on simulator?).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add localized title and description in iTunes connect. After that the IAP worked like a charm. *doh